# How to make Pane transperent but not its children node in javafx

Tags: javafx, opacity

i want to create a screen in which the pane(borderpane in my case) will have opacity of .8 and its children node will have opacity of 1.

I made this but after running this i found that opacity gets inherited from borderlayout pane to its children node. Is there any way through which i can keep the opacity of children node intact?

Let me know if you need more clarification on this.

Comment: You can override the opacity of the child to 1 by explicitly defining it.

Comment: The usual way that all users want usually is to set opacity to the parent and all children will also have inherit it. So yours is in not usual use case, so imo there is no way other than setting the children explicitly as @ItachiUchiha commented above.